# React Js - Llenar un array de números, de forma dinámica

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

Estoy, realizando una app, en la cual se deben insertar distintas cifras de forma dinámica en un array, que como tal son precios, lo realizo estableciendo los datos desde un input, al imprimir  el array solo me indica el número ingresado recientemente y nos los previos, para ello empleo el método push(); por otra parte, los imprime como string y requiero que sean números como tal; lo he intentado de la siguiente forma:

```
const FormPricesUsed = () => {
  let pricesUsed = [];

  const [prices, setPrices] = useState(0);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      pricesUsed.push(prices)
      setPrices('')
      console.log(pricesUsed)
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
      switch (e.target.name) {
          case 'prices':
              setPrices(e.target.value)         
          break;
            default:
              break;
      }
  }

  return (
      <Container>
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input 
                  type="number"
                  name="prices"
                  value={prices}
                  onChange={handleChange}
              /> 
          </Form>
      </Container>
   );
}
export default FormPricesUsed;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por favor fijate sin con estas modificaciones tu codigo corre como vos necesitas.

```js
const FormPricesUsed = () => {

  const [prices, setPrices] = useState([]);
  const [pricesUsed, setPricesUsed] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setPricesUsed([...pricesUsed, prices])
      setPrices([])
      console.log(pricesUsed)
  }

  const handleChange = (e) =>  
      {e.target.name == 'prices' && setPrices([...prices, parseInt(e.target.value)])  }
   

  return (
      <Container>
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input 
                  type="number"
                  name="prices"
                  value={prices}
                  onChange={handleChange}
              /> 
          </Form>
      </Container>
   );
}
export default FormPricesUsed;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Si funcionó, solo hay un problema, que al insertar los datos y al presionar entrar para que se establezcan en el array, no se agrega, posteriormente agrego otro y ahí se establece el primero.